# Comparing 気にする vs. 気になる

Tags: word-choice, words, meaning, idioms

Consider this [example sentence from SPACEALC](http://eow.alc.co.jp/%E6%B0%97%E3%81%AB%E3%81%AA%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%81%9F/UTF-8/?ref=sa):

> あなたがどうしているか気になっていた。　
>   "I was concerned about how you were."

What is the difference when `気にする` is used instead? I.e.,

> あなたがどうしているか気にしていた。

`～なる` seems to convey "spontaneity" or "arising from nowhere" while `～する` seems to convey deliberate agency. Would `～する` mean to be deliberately concerned about the person? The `～する` version seems to be "more concerned" than the `～なる` version because of explicit agency.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, in that example, the only difference would be the deliberateness, and as a potential difference, the degree of the concern. `気にする` is to be concerned about something to the point of being bothered/disturbed by it. `気になる` could also mean the same, but not necessarily so. Depending on the context and tone, `気になっていた` could be anywhere between lighthearted and grave.

Note that `気にする` and `気になる` are not always interchangeable. `気にする` is to mind/care/worry as a generally negative emotion, while `気になる` is broader and can be a neutral or positive feeling as well. So, when you are “interested by” rather than “concerned about” something, it is always `〜なる` and never `〜する`.

Here is an example that I think illustrates the different connotations. Let’s say you are talking about an artist who unveiled a new painting:

> 彼は自分の作品が人にどう思われるか気になっていた
>   “He *wondered* what people would think of his work.”

Similar to the usage of the word “wonder” in English, whether the artist is simply *curious* in what people would think, or whether he is somewhat *worried* about their opinion, is not apparent in this one sentence. It is context-dependent.

> 彼は自分の作品が人にどう思われるか気にしていた
>   “He was *concerned* with what people would think of his work.”

This, on the other hand, shows a value judgement of the *effects* of the artist’s interest in people’s opinions. You are saying that his interest affects him in a negative way. The extent of these negative effects can range anywhere from “it makes him a tiny bit anxious” to “he is preoccupied by it” to “he is destructively obsessed by it,” but in any case you have made a judgement that the effects on him are neither positive nor neutral.

Comment: If you could provide example cases your answer would be much better.

Comment: I added an example. Hope that helps. I think that last paragraph pretty much sums it up for any situation.